Imputation Missing data
I have a longitudinal data set with 2 dependent variables (couple) - a husband and a wife. There were 2 waves for the husbands and 3 waves for the wives. Since there is a lot of missing data, I decided to exclude all participants where either the wife was absent for >1 of the waves and/or where the husband missed ≥1 appointment. However, in this way I lose a lot of data.
For example, I have the following case: the wife was present at every wave, but the husband missed 1 appointment.  According to my rules, I should exclude the couple.
My consideration is to keep the couple even though the husband only attended 1 appointment, but this way it won't be a longitudinal sample and the results will probably be biased after imputation?

This situation should be approached with multiple imputation (MI), as explained by Stef van Buuren in Flexible Imputation of Missing Data. The complete-case restriction of your proposed "rules" tends to lead to bias, not just to a loss of data values.
MI works well when data are missing at random (MAR)* in a technical sense. Performing multiple imputations, analyzing each of the imputed data sets separately, then properly pooling results from all analyses accounts for the uncertainty arising from imputation while allowing all individuals/couples to contribute. With MAR data, MI estimates can be unbiased and have valid confidence intervals.
The reference also explains how these approaches can be extended to handle some situations in which the data are "missing not at random" (MNAR).

*MAR is less restrictive than "missing completely at random" (MCAR). It means that there are no systematic reasons for missingness outside of what might be explained by the observed data and design factors.

There are several questions here. I don't mean any of the following to be unfriendly, but I'm trying to interpret your questions and the useful answers are just not coming. Hopefully this will help you clarify your actual question.

Is it okay break your my own rules on excluding data? [paraphrased]

Uhm.. Counterquestion, okay in what way?

It won't be a longitudinal sample?

I don't think a "longitudinal sample" is really a thing. But, in your data, there will indeed be a single measurement for the individual, or one of them is missing, depending on how you enter your data.

It will be biased after imputation?

If you still act as if a measurement was taken and then impute some other variable, this will influence the results, yes.


Is it okay to break my own rules on excluding data? [paraphrased] - yes, exactly
If I keep the man who only came for 1 appointment, there won't be a follow-up, so there won't be enough data for imputation.
yes, in all cases the results will be biased, but I don't know how far and if it makes sense to keep participants who only attended 1 wave.


What makes sense depends on the topic of your research. If it's okay to continue with missing data at all is already debatable, perhaps read a bit from here https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-MCAR.html.

I will check it out. Thank you.

You still have a dataset of "mean observation for husband" which you can compare with "mean observation for wife".
But you can't include these extra cases if your interest is "change for husband" compared with "change for wife".
